# How to keep the ID the same for a list when appending

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to obtain a list without changing the ID of the original list and the list can only contain spaces between each element.

I keep getting this error and I am unable to find a way to keep its ID the same whilst having only spaces in between each element whilst printing it out.

```
    newlist=[array[x] for x in range(len(array)) if x !=0]
    array=[]
    array.append(newlist)
    newlist=[]
    print(' '.join(array))
```

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

The error message is for the last line

```
while ans:


    ans=input("\nSelect an option?\n")

    if ans=="A":
        if len(array) < 10:
            A = list(input('\nInput string: \n'))
            if len(A) == 1 and str(A):
                array += A
            if len(array) == 10:
                print( "Invalid input\n")   

    elif ans=="P":
      print(' '.join(array))

    elif ans=="N":

        newlist=[array[x] for x in range(len(array)) if x !=0]
        array=[]
        array.append(newlist)
        newlist=[]
        print(' '.join(array))


    elif ans=="M":
      print(id(array))
```

This is what half the code looks like.

What I intend is that the ID should always stay the same and when N is inputted the first element of the array is removed

No use of  **pop**, **del**, **remove**, **slicing** and **index** is allowed

Comment: does `array` have a pervious value before your list comprehension statement? If not, you're using `array` before its defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about "clear" then? :) Python 3.3 and higher

```
elif ans=="N":

    newlist=[array[x] for x in range(len(array)) if x !=0]
    array.clear()
    array.extend(newlist)
    print(' '.join(array))
```

Comment: The N input should remove the first element of the array whilst keeping the ID the same

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I cannot use pop, del, remove, slicing and index.